# jquery append() with tag not working

Tags: jquery, append

Example:

```
<div>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <span>world</span>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>hello2</h1>
    <span>world3</span>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>hello4</h1>
    <span>world5</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div').each(function(){
        var $zag = $(this).find('h1');
    $(this).append('<div style="color:red">' + $zag + "</div>");
    });
```

I want replace 'h1' to new 'div'. This scheme gives error [Object object] This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q2CxV/

add: I want this:

```
<div>
    <div style="color:red">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <span>world</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="color:red">
      <h1>hello2</h1>
      <span>world3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="color:red">
       <h1>hello4</h1>
       <span>world5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? What do you gain from nesting a div within a div that you couldn't do with CSS alone?

Answer (score 0):

`$zag` will give you `DOM` object. I think you want it's html so

Try this

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var $zag = $(this).find($('h1'));
  $(this).append('<div style="color:red">' + $zag.html() + "</div>");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q2CxV/1/)

**UPDATE**
To remove the existing "h1" and append it with a div tag use it like below

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var $zag = $(this).find($('h1'));
  $zag.remove();
  $(this).append('<div style="color:red"><h1>' + $zag.html() + "</h1></div>");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q2CxV/3/)

Comment: I want remove h1 with tag, not only text. See I add to 1st post

Comment: it works, but make clone h1, and I want to remove h1 to new div like example from https://api.jquery.com/append/ with h2

Comment: no, and if I need remove inside new div 'h1' and 'span'  what to do

Comment: @user3584923, it will give you the same html as you wanted. You can check this in Fiddle link by using inspect element for browser console window.

Answer (score 0):

The object you want to substitute in the string.

```
<script>

$('div').each(function() {
    var $zag = $(this).find('h1');
    var div = $('<div/>').css({style: 'color:red'});
    div.append($zag);

    $(this).append(div);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

### DEMO

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var $zag = $(this).find('h1');
    $zag.wrap('<div style="color:red"/>').parent().appendTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work.

```
$('div').each(function(){
var $zag = $(this).find('h1');
$(this).wrap('<div style="color:red">' + $($zag)[0].innerHTML + "</div>");
});
```